# Where is "START" searching for executables?

Tags: windows, matlab, batch-file, cmd

In my company we use a batch-file to start Matlab. The batch-file prepares the environment before starting Matlab.

Matlab itself is started with

```
START MATLAB.EXE
```

I have several versions of Matlab installed on my system. And this command is starting the wrong Matlab version. Where is START looking for the executables?

Comment: This might help you: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/80978-mutliple-copies-of-matlab-on-the-same-machine-how-to-set-the-default

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Command **start** finds executables to run like command line interpreter **cmd.exe** does if no absolute path is used, using additionally the extensions listed in environment variable **PATHEXT** separated by semicolons if file extension is also missing.

1. Current working directory.
2. All directories of environment variable **PATH** in order as listed in **PATH**.

   Just type in a command prompt window `set path` to see all directories in **PATH** as well as all file extensions in **PATHEXT**.

   Please note that each user account has its own **PATH**. Therefore **PATH** of system account is usually different to **PATH** of a standard user account. That is very important on running a batch file with command [runas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/runas) or via task scheduler using a different account.

   The batch file posted by [Jason Faulkner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962346/jason-faulkner) is very helpful here, too.
3. **start** looks further in registry under the keys

   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths

   Applications installed with an MSI package (embedded in installer EXE or published separately) using [msiexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc759262(v=ws.10)) have their file name registered under **App Paths** with default string value containing name of executable with full path. There is often a second string value with name **Path** containing just the full path to the executable of the application. Other installers register an application also in `App Paths`, see Microsoft documentation page [Application Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration).

The **App Paths** key in [registry hive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-hives) `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` usually does not exist as installation is done using trusted installer or local administrator account and therefore the registration of the installed application is done in registry hive `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. But on a per user installation of an application the `HKCU` path is used for application registration instead of `HKLM` path.

The **App Paths** key under **Wow6432Node** key exists only on Windows x64. But x86 applications are registered nevertheless usually in both **App Paths** although **Wow6432Node** is for 32-bit applications and the other tree for 64-bit applications on Windows 7 x64, Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 and later Windows x64. For details see Microsoft article [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys).

One more note:

Even with `.exe` specified, **start** searches in current working directory as well as in directories of **PATH** after not found `AppName.exe` additionally for `AppName.exe.*` and checks file extension (string after last period) against the file extensions in **PATHEXT** if this returns one or more file names. It is nevertheless always better to specify the file extension of the application to start as a search for `AppName.exe` is always done first before the wildcard search is executed if `AppName.exe` could not be found in the current directory.

The free tool [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) of Sysinternals (Microsoft) is a great tool to find out things like that.

Last but not least for none executables **start** checks also HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT for a file association to open a file or a URI (URL) with associated application defined for command **open**. That is the reason why something like below also works.

```
start MyTextFile.txt
start https://stackoverflow.com/
```

`%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` containing the code for `start` uses the Windows shell function [ShellExecuteEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexa) for executing applications or opening files or URLs with associated application.

Comment: Thank you. Step 3 of your answer helped to solve my problem. Matlab was not included in PATH but changing every registry entry to point to the new Matlab version helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this batch file to detect where the system resolves the EXE in question:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Save this as C:\CheckPath.bat

IF NOT "%~$PATH:1" == "" (
    ECHO %~$PATH:1
) ELSE (
    ECHO Could not find "%~1" inside of a registered PATH.
)
```

Now running:

- `C:\CheckPath.bat cmd.exe` returns `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`
- `C:\CheckPath.bat NotValid.exe` returns `Could not find "NotValid.exe" inside of a registered PATH.`

Try running `CheckPath.bat MATLAB.exe` and you can see where the system is resolving the path to.

Note - this will resolve the directory assuming you are not redefining `%PATH%` in your script.

Comment: Doesn't the `WHERE` command do the same thing?