# Create batch file to run .exe on both 32-bit and 64-bit OS

Tags: batch-file, 32bit-64bit

I am able to create a batch file to run an application like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder\myapp.exe"
```

But since the OS of the client's workstation is 32-bit OS (mine is 64-bit OS), how can I write a command that I can run on my workstation and the client as well?

Answer (score 1):

```
:CheckOS
IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%" (GOTO 64BIT) ELSE (GOTO 32BIT)

:64BIT
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder\myapp.exe" 
GOTO END

:32BIT
START "" "C:\Program Files\Folder\myapp.exe" 
GOTO END

:END
```

Refer: [batch file to check 64bit or 32bit OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12322308/batch-file-to-check-64bit-or-32bit-os)

Comment: What if the Windows is **not** installed on `C:`?

Comment: i don't think you understood what i wrote, it checks your os whether it is on c: or D: then it goes for 64 bit or 32 bit. After that it is starting the program that is in C:\ . So, if your windows is not installed on C: your filepath would simply had been C:\yourfolder\yourapp.exe.

Comment: The `Program Files` directories are located on the same drive as the `Windows` directory (not necessarily on `C:`). Even more, the localized versions of Windows use localized names for this directory. (I don't know for the Windows 7 and newer but this is how it used to work on Windows XP and previous versions.) The test using `%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%` is the correct way to do it but also use the environment variables to create the path of the application to start.

Comment: what if `%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%` is not `C:\Program Files (x86)`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a batch code which really searches first for the application to start before starting it.

```
@echo off
rem The program files folder exists on all Windows.
for /R "%ProgramFiles%" %%I in (myapp*.exe) do (
    start "" "%%I"
    goto :EOF
)

rem The x86 program files folder exists only on all Windows x64.
if not "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "" (
    for /R "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" %%I in (myapp*.exe) do (
        start "" "%%I"
        goto :EOF
    )
)

echo Can't find myapp.exe in any program files folder.
echo.
pause
```

But if the application is installed with adding its executable name as key to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
```

or to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
```

the command **start** would find the application to start by itself on specifying just `myapp.exe`. See the answers on [Where is “START” searching for executables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386403/3074564) and [How to enumerate all programs that can open XML file as plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31603179/3074564) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Try checking to see if the directory exists, like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%" (
    START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder\myapp.exe" 
) ELSE (
    START "" "C:\Program Files\Folder\myapp.exe" 
)
```

Comment: What if the Windows is **not** installed on `C:`?

Comment: and what if `%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%` is not `C:\Program Files (x86)`, like in Windows for another language?