# findstr not bringing back correct files

Tags: cmd, windows-server-2012-r2, findstr

I am running the windows command findstr to search for a specific sting only in `.ini` files. The command I am running is `findstr /i /s /m /C:\output *.ini` looking for the string `\output`. The following is the output from the command

```
etc\billdirfile.ini
etc\doc1dirfile.ini
etc\ENVIRON.INI_20150902_0944
etc\ENVIRON.INI_20150903_1035
```

I expect a file `etc\environ.ini` to show up in that list but it does not. When I rerun the command with an added wildcard at the end `findstr /i /s /m /C:\output *.ini*` my out put is as follows.

```
etc\billdirfile.ini
etc\doc1dirfile.ini
etc\ENVIRON.INI
etc\ENVIRON.INI.bak
etc\ENVIRON.INI_20150901_1021
etc\ENVIRON.INI_20150901_1050
etc\ENVIRON.INI_20150901_1431
etc\ENVIRON.INI_20150901_1433
etc\ENVIRON.INI_20150901_1438
etc\ENVIRON.INI_20150902_0944
etc\ENVIRON.INI_20150902_0954
etc\ENVIRON.INI_20150903_1035
etc\ENVIRON.INI_20150903_1042
etc\ENVIRON.INI_20150903_1344
etc\ENVIRON.INI_20150922_1305
```

I have two questions based on this output.

1) Why without the additional wildcard i.e. `*.ini` at the end does the `environ.ini` file that I expect to see not show up ? I checked the name of the file there are no additional spaces or characters at the end.

2) why does these two files

```
etc\ENVIRON.INI_20150902_0944
etc\ENVIRON.INI_20150903_1035
```

show up without the added wildcard at the end i.e. without `*.ini*`. I expect I would only see `.ini` files only.

Also testing this on another machine

```
findstr /i /s /m /c:\output *.ini
etc\billdirfile.ini
etc\doc1dirfile.ini
etc\ENVIRON.INI
etc\ENVIRON.INI_20150825_1521
```

the findstr command finds the `etc\environ.ini` file without an issue. Both machines are running server 2012 R2 and are exactly the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Mack

Comment: The search string after `/C:` should be placed within `""`; I'd also recommend to (binary) compare the `findstr.exe` files on the machines, maybe they are of different versions...

Comment: I tired with the addition of quotes and it does not make a difference the issue remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

When using in a batch file just file name of a console application like `findstr` without file extension and without complete path, command line processor searches first in current directory and next in all directories defined in environment variable **PATH** for `findstr*` and checks if any found file has a file extension defined in environment variable **PATHEXT**.

To see the current values of **PATH** and **PATHEXT** run in a command prompt window `set path` which lists all environment variables starting with `path` in name.

As NTFS file system driver returns file names always in alphabetic order, a `findstr.bat` is used first by command processor as found first prior to `findst.exe` perhaps also existing in same directory which is often not wanted. By the way: Internal commands of `cmd.exe` like `echo` are used only if no executable file could be found having name `echo` and a file extension listed in **PATHEXT**.

So it could be that just `findstr` in the batch file does on one of the two computers not result in executing `findstr.exe` in system32 directory of Windows, but in using a different `findstr.*` found in one of the directories in **PATH** having a file extension listed in **PATHEXT**.

It is always more safe to specify in batch files console applications like `findstr.exe` with full path and with file extension, i.e. use `%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe` instead of just `findstr`.

You should check if there is a file with name `findstr` with a file extension listed in **PATHEXT** in any directory listed in **PATH**. The batch file [CheckPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27383307/3074564) by [Jason Faulkner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962346/jason-faulkner) could be useful to find out if there is `findstr.bat` or `findstr.com` or `finstr.exe` and in which directory of **PATH** found first.

The answer for your second question why with `*.ini` also `ENVIRON.INI_20150902_0944` and `ENVIRON.INI_20150903_1035` are processed by **findstr** is:

The short names of the files are `ENVIRON~3.INI` and `ENVIRON~4.INI`.

(The numbers are most likely different on your computer.)

The kernel function used by **findstr** and **dir** for searching for files with a given pattern takes also the short file names into account and not only the long file names. Run `dir /S /X *.ini` and you see all files found with `*.ini` because of a match on long or short file name.

I have no idea why `environ.ini` is not listed on first output. Perhaps you can find out the reason by looking on short names of all `*.ini` in directory `etc`.