# What could be the reason for batch file with just REG ADD command looping endless?

Tags: batch-file

I have below line in my batch file `test.bat` which adds an entry to Windows registry:

```
@echo off
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Server" /v DisplayName /t REG_SZ /d Server /f
```

The command is working when I run the same line from within a command prompt window. But it results in an infinite loop when I put this line into batch file `test.bat` and run the batch file on Windows 7.

What could be the reason for this unexpected batch file processing?

Comment: What is the batch-file that is running this called? Make sure you don't call it REG.bat or something like that because than it will see reg not as a command but as a call to itself

Comment: Which Windows version you are using? Do you can query the key or does it fails too? `REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Server" /v DisplayName`

Comment: when I run the same line on command prompt its working but when I put this line in batch file its going infinite loop. I am using windows 7. The name of batch file is test.bat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is advisable to call applications like `reg` not being an internal command of Windows command processor `cmd.exe` in batch files always with full path and with file extension instead of just file name.

```
@echo off
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Server" /v DisplayName /t REG_SZ /d Server /f
```

With using just `REG` it depends on which file extensions for executables/scripts are defined in environment variable **PATHEXT** of current command process and which directories are defined in environment variable **PATH** of current command process. The order of directories is in this case also important.

See answer on [Where is “START” searching for executables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386403/3074564) for more details about search for executable. But please note that although **start** is for all Windows NT based Windows an internal command of command processor `cmd.exe`, command processor itself uses only **PATHEXT** and **PATH** and ignores **App Paths** keys in Windows registry. The file searching behavior of Windows command interpreter is explained even more detailed in answer on [What is the reason for '...' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564)

The infinite loop is most likely caused by naming the batch file `reg.bat` as supposed already by [Dennis van Gils](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5022761/dennis-van-gils). So command processor finds in current directory on searching for an executable with name `REG` the file `reg.bat` which is already processed and continues batch processing on this batch file with passing the other strings as parameter to `reg.bat`. In other words the batch file starts itself again and again in an endless loop.

One more note:

The console application `reg.exe` should be used here to **add** a string value to registry hive **HKEY_LOCALE_MACHINE**. This write operation for entire machine requires administrator privileges. Therefore either user account control (UAC) is disabled for current user using this batch file or *Run as Administrator* respectively [Runas](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) is used on executing this batch file. Otherwise `reg.exe` fails to add the string value to registry because of missing permissions.