# How to open a *.xlsx file containing a space in file name found by command DIR in Excel?

Tags: excel, batch-file

I have a batch file that opens an Excel file with a space as well as date in its file name.

For example: `Book 1-27Aug2016`

Currently, I am having trouble disabling the delimiters so that command **start** doesn't try to open two files: `Book.xlsx` and `1-27Aug2016.xlsx`

Here is my code:

```
for /f "delims=*" %%# in ('dir /tw /o-d /b "Book 1-*"') do (start excel %%#& exit)
```

I referenced the web page in SS64 Windows CMD Shell forum below for disabling/modifying delimiters, but I still have yet to experience success.

[For /f documentation](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1544)

Lastly, once I remove the space from the file name, the batch runs without any issues.

What do I need to modify in the single line batch code to open also an Excel file with a space in file name in Excel?

Comment: Just use `"delims="` to say there are no delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a command prompt window, run in this window `for /?` and read very carefully all output help pages.

Command **FOR** with option `/F` splits up a string by default on spaces/tabs. It can be either used `"tokens=*"` or `"delims="` to avoid this string splitting. The usage of `"delims=*"` works also for file names because the name of a file without or with path can't contain an asterisk. But `"delims=*"` is usually not used to prevent splitting up a string into tokens because a string read from a text file, output of an application or an environment variable could contain 1 or more asterisks as well.

Next run in a command prompt window `cmd /?` and read at least last output help page on which is explained on which characters in name of a file/folder without or with path the file/folder name string must be enclosed in double quotes. In general it is advisable to enclose file/folder names without/with path always in double quotes.

The command **DIR** returns with the used options just the names of the files without path and always without surrounding double quotes as it can be seen on running in a command prompt window in directory with `Book 1-*` files

```
dir "Book 1-*" /A-D /B /O-D /TW
```

after first running `dir /?` to get displayed the help for command **DIR**.

So used should be:

```
for /F "delims=" %%# in ('dir "Book 1-*" /A-D /B /O-D /TW 2^>nul') do ( start "" excel.exe "%%#" & exit /B )
```

`2^>nul` is `2>nul` whereby the [redirection operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx) `>` is escaped with `^` to apply this redirection on running command **DIR** instead of being interpreted as redirection of command **FOR** at an invalid position in command line. The command **DIR** outputs the error message `File not found` to handle **STDERR** if it can't find any file in current directory matching the pattern `Book 1-*`. This error message is suppressed by redirecting it to device **NUL**.

It is advisable to specify the application to start with file extension if well known even if the path is not known. Read answer on [Where is “START” searching for executables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382626/) for an explanation.

In the batch command line above there are after command **START** also two double quotes before the name of the executable to start. Usage of `""` is highly recommended as command **START** interprets often first double quoted string in arguments list as optional title string. By specifying explicitly an in this case empty title string helps to avoid unexpected application execution. For details on command **START** run in command prompt window `start /?`.

And last it is better to use command **EXIT** with parameter `/B` to exit just processing of current batch file and not exit entire command process. If this batch file is called with command **CALL** from another batch file or started from within a command prompt window and command **EXIT** is used without parameter `/B`, the processing would not continue on parent batch file respectively command prompt window would be closed by **EXIT**, too. There is no difference between usage of `exit` and `exit /B` if this batch file is executed by a double click on the batch file. For details on command **EXIT** run in a command prompt window `exit /?`.

By the way: The command **START** uses file association registration data if it can find an executable or script with given name to open the specified file with the registered application for the file extension.

So it would be also possible to use:

```
for /F "delims=" %%# in ('dir "Book 1-*" /A-D /B /O-D /TW 2^>nul') do ( start "" "%%#" & exit /B )
```

Now command **START** opens the *.xslx file with whatever application is associated with this file extension as default application for opening it.

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly!! Also thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Add double quotes around the last variable.

```
for /f "delims=*" %%# in ('dir /tw /o-d /b "Book 1-*"') do (start excel "%%#"& exit)
```