# Execute .bat file automatically via command line getting https error

Tags: batch-file, cmd, cron

Here is my .bat file script.

```
cmd /k "https://exampleserver.com/server/php/ping.php"
```

When i run .the file via command line it says

```
'https:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can i run this without any error from command line ? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Huh??? I haven't a clue what you mean by *"it is executing automatically via chrome browser. But I want this to execute via command line"*. Assuming your question has any value, I'm not sure it belongs on StackOverflow. It may be better suited to SuperUser. But you need to explain your problem better either way.

Comment: I mean to execute via command line what should i write in the .bat file? for example start command and the program name like that

Comment: Windows command interpreter can execute only commands, executables and certain scripts. It can't open an URL using a protocol like [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Https). This can be done only by applications written for that purpose, for example wwww browsers. You can use the command __START__ which finds out which application is associated with protocol HTTPS, i.e. use `start "" "https://exampleserver.com/server/php/ping.php"`. Run `start /?` in a cmd prompt window for details and see [Where is “START” searching for executables?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27386403/3074564)

Comment: When i run the file like above i am getting output in browser . Can't we get the output in cmd itself without open the browser?

Comment: google for `wget`. A command line tool for downloading websites.

Comment: @user3408779 no, You cant do that, even if you do, you cant. You can do it in Ubuntu's commandline, but not in windows command line.