# Batch to check if process exists

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I'd like a batch that will check if the process firefox.exe exists (after it has been started by the start command).
If the process exists, it will go to the label :fullscreen,
else the batch will go the the label :timeout. Then, it will check again if the process firefox.exe exists and if not, it will go again to the label :fullscreen until the process exists.

Here is my batch:

```
@echo off
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
:timeout
timeout /t 5
:fullscreen
nircmd sendkeypress F11
exit
```

How can I do this check ?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use QUERY PROCESS:

```bat
@Echo Off
If Not Exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" Exit/B
Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
:Loop
Timeout 5 /NoBreak>Nul
QProcess firefox.exe>Nul 2>&1||GoTo :Loop
NirCmd SendKeyPress F11
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest for this task the batch file:

```
@echo off
start "" /max firefox.exe
if errorlevel 1 goto :EOF
set LoopCount=0

:WaitLoop
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq firefox.exe" 2>nul | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "firefox.exe" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 nircmd.exe sendkeypress F11 & goto :EOF
set /A LoopCount+=1
if not %LoopCount% == 6 goto WaitLoop
```

Let me explain the few command lines used here.

---

### 1. Starting Firefox

The command **START** being an internal command of `cmd.exe` interprets the first double quoted string as optional title for the console window. Therefore the command line

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

results just in opening a new console window with the window title:
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe**

For that reason `""` is specified as first **START** argument to define an empty title. **Firefox** is a GUI application. So no console window is opened which means an empty window title is really enough.

The parameter `/max` would not be really necessary, but the goal is to get **Firefox** into full screen mode after starting. So why not starting it already maximized?

32-bit version of **Firefox** is by default installed in directory `%ProgramFiles%` on 32-bit Windows and in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` on 64-bit Windows. But it is possible during the installation to install **Firefox** into any other folder. But **Firefox** installer is well coded and registers `firefox.exe` in Windows registry under key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
```

This is recommended by Microsoft as written in MSDN article [Application Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration).

The command **START** searches also in Windows registry under this key for an executable specified as argument without path as explained in answer on [Where is “START” searching for executables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386403/3074564)

This is the reason for using just `firefox.exe` on **START** command line because that starts an installed **Firefox** independent on installation location.

**START** displays an appropriate message box if `firefox.exe` could not be started and exits in this case with a return code greater 0 (9059 in my test on one computer).

The help output on running `if /?` in a command prompt window explains how to evaluate the exit code of a previous command or application without usage of immediate or delayed environment variable expansion and therefore working anywhere in a batch file from MS-DOS (really!) to currently latest Windows 10.

The command line `if errorlevel 1 goto :EOF` means **IF** `start` failed to start `firefox.exe` indicated by an exit code **greater or equal 1 THEN** exit execution of this batch file. For details on exiting batch file execution see answer on [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)

---

### 2. Checking for running Firefox

The command **TASKLIST** being an external command, i.e. a console application in system directory of Windows, outputs a list of running processes. This list can be already filtered by **TASKLIST** itself for a specific process as done in batch file with `/FI "IMAGENAME eq firefox.exe"`.

But **TASKLIST** is designed for just printing a list of processes. It is not designed for checking if a specific process is running and returning the result to the calling process via exit code. **TASKLIST** always exits with 0.

But an error message is output to handle **STDERR** on using a filter and no process can be found in process list matching this filter. For that reason `2>nul` is used to suppress this error message by redirecting it to device NUL. Read the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for more information about redirection.

A simple method to get a simple false/true respectively 0/1 result on checking for running **Firefox** is filtering output of **TASKLIST** with external command **FIND** which exits with 0 if the string to find was indeed found or with 1 if the searched string could not be found in the text read in this case from **STDIN**. The output of **FIND** is of no interest and therefore suppressed with redirection to device **NUL** using `>nul`.

Instead of using **TASKLIST** and **FIND** it is also possible to use **QPROCESS**:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\qprocess.exe firefox.exe >nul 2>&1
```

**QPROCESS** exits with exit code `1` if `firefox.exe` could not be found in list of running processes. Otherwise the exit code is `0` on `firefox.exe` is running.

---

### 3. Evaluating Firefox process checking result

```
if not errorlevel 1 nircmd.exe sendkeypress F11 & goto :EOF
```

The **IF** command checks if exit code of **FIND** is **NOT greater or equal 1** which means if exit code is **lower than 1**. Command **FIND** exits never with a negative value. So if this condition is true then it is time to execute `nircmd.exe` to send key press <kbd>F11</kbd> to application in foreground hopefully being **Firefox** (not guaranteed by this code) and exit batch file processing.

Otherwise the batch file should wait once again 5 seconds and then do the check again. This can very easily result in an endless running batch file in case of started **Firefox** is immediately closed by the user before the 5 seconds wait timed out. For that reason it is counted how often the wait loop is already executed. After 6 loop runs, or 30 seconds, it is really time to no longer wait for **Firefox** and exit the batch file.

---

### 4. Getting more information about used commands

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `find /?`
- `if /?`
- `qprocess /?`
- `set /?`
- `start /?`
- `tasklist /?`
- `timeout /?`

And [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) should be also read explaining operator `&` in addition to all other web pages referenced already above.

Answer (score 1):

You can show a list of opened programs like this:

```
tasklist
```

To check if firefox exists:

EDIT: Code edited to show a fully working example

```
@echo off
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
goto :checkloop

:checkloop
tasklist|find "firefox.exe" > NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 ( 
    call :fullscreen 
    exit
) else ( 
     call :timeout
     goto :checkloop
)


:fullscreen
nircmd sendkeypress F11
goto :EOF

:timeout
timeout /t 5
goto :EOF
```