# Find the path of executable and store the executable in a variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to create a batch file:
The batch file will locate the path of executable first. Then, the path will be stored in a variable for later use.

This is my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set directoryName=dir/s c:\ABCD.exe
rem run command
cmd /c %directoryName%
pause 
endlocal
```

The command prompt does return me with the executable's path but the path is not stored in the variable. Why is it so?

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set commands output as a variable in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359820/how-to-set-commands-output-as-a-variable-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: The executable your are searching for by searching for a file on entire drive `C:` is perhaps installed always well registered according to Microsoft's guidelines for [Application Registration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121.aspx). In this case it would not be necessary at all to search all drives of a hard disk for the executable. Many applications are correct registered making it possible to use them from command line with command `start` without path, see [Where is “START” searching for executables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386403/3074564)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your question, it appears that you're not really wanting to save the path of the executable file at all, but the file name complete with it's full path:

I prefer the `Where` command for this type of search, this example searches the drive in which the current directory resides:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "mPth="
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where /R \ "ABCD.exe" /F 2^>Nul'
) Do Set "mPth=%%A"
If Not Defined mPth Exit /B
Rem Rest of code goes here
```

The variable `%mPth%` should contain what you need. I have designed it to automatically enclose the variable value in doublequotes, if you wish to not have those, change `%%A` on line `4` to `%%~A`. If the file is not found then the script will just `Exit`, if you wish it to do something else then you can add that functionality on line `5`.

***Note:*** the code could find more than one match, if it does it will save the variable value to the last one matched, which may not be the one you intended. A robust solution might want to include for this possibility.

**Edit** *(this sets the variable, `%mPth%` to the path of the executable file only)*

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "mPth="
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where /R \ "ABCD.exe" /F 2^>Nul'
) Do Set "mPth=%%~dpA"
If Not Defined mPth Exit /B
Set "mPth=%mPth:~,-1%"
Rem Rest of code goes here
```

Comment: The code works well! Thanks for your input. By the way, if I was looking for the path without the filename, can I use the same command (the where command)?

Comment: @YongShunTeo, I've added an Edit section regarding your latest comment.

Answer (score 0):

Lets walk through your code

```
set directoryName=dir/s c:\ABCD.exe
```

This fills the variable `directory` name with the value `dir/s c:\ABCD.exe`.

```
cmd /c %directoryName%
```

This executes the command in `directoryname`. There is no line in your code that saves the files location to a variable.

---

Extracting the path of a file can be done as follows

```
@echo off
setlocal
set executable=c:\location\ABCD.exe
FOR %%A IN ("%executable%") DO Set executablepath=%%~dpA
echo executablepath: %executablepath%
pause 
endlocal
```

`%executablepath%` will contain `c:\location\`

Answer (score 0):

The value that you are assigning to `directoryname` is `dir /s c:\abc.exe`.

this value is then substituted for `%directoryname%` in your `cmd` line, which *executes* the command `dir/s...`, showing you the location(s) of `abc.exe` in the familiar `dir` format.

If what you want is just the directoryname in `directoryname`, then you need

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /B /a-d "c:\abc.exe"') do set "directoryname=%%~dpa"
```

which will first execute the `dir` command, then process each line of output from that command and assign it in its entirety to `%%a`.

The `dir` command shown would "display" the matching names found in the nominated directory (`c:\`) and its subdirectories (`/s`) in basic form (`/b`) - that is, names only, no size or date or report-headers or report-footers, and `a-d` without directorynames (should they match the "mask" `abc.exe`)

The `delims=` option to the `for /f` command instructs that the entire line as output by the command in single-quotes, be assigned to `%%a`.

When the result is assigned to the variable `directoryname`, only the **D**rive and **P**ath parts are selected by using the `~dp` prefix the the `a`.

Note that only the very last name found will be assigned to the variable as any earlier assignment will be overwritten by a succeeding assignment.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be what you are looking for. This script searches through the `PATH` variable and looks for files that have and extension in the `PATHEXT` variable list.

```
@SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@SET EXITCODE=1

:: Needs an argument.

@IF "x%1"=="x" (
    @ECHO Usage: %0 ^<progName^>
    GOTO TheEnd
)

@set newline=^


@REM Previous two (2) blank lines are required. Do not change!

@REM Ensure that the current working directory is first
@REM because that is where DOS looks first.
@PATH=.;!PATH!

@FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in ("%PATH:;=!newline!%") DO @(
    @IF EXIST %%i\%1 (
        @ECHO %%i\%1
        @SET EXITCODE=0
    )

    @FOR /F "tokens=*" %%x in ("%PATHEXT:;=!newline!%") DO @(
        @IF EXIST %%i\%1%%x (
            @ECHO %%i\%1%%x
            @SET EXITCODE=0
        )
    )
)

:TheEnd
@EXIT /B %EXITCODE%
```

Note that this may find multiple executables. It may also find multiple types of executables. The current directory is also included first since that is what the shell, `cmd.exe`, does.

```
M:>whence wc
.\wc.BAT
.\wc.VBS
C:\Users\lit\bin\wc.BAT
C:\Users\lit\bin\wc.VBS
```