# Batch file to find chrome installed path dynamically

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, kiosk-mode

I need to check for the chrome browser in any Windows system by running a .bat file. The batch file should be able to check if Chrome browser is installed in the system. if its installed want to store the path in a variable and use that.I am creating chrome kiosk app..so need to find the chrome path dynamically.Please help me

```
start  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk --fullscreen --incognito "website url"
```

Comment: `where chrome` assuming it is installed properly.

Comment: if user change the chrome default installed location,i want to identify that location dynamically when i strat bat file.that's my requirement..in windows 10 the default location is C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe,but windows 7 it is different..

Comment: have you tried `where chrome` ?

Comment: i am using windows 10,here its installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe..

Comment: no, I am asking, have you tried the command? open `cmd.exe` and type `where chrome` then press enter

Comment: i am using .bat file ..not windows cmd..

Comment: Batch files are files that stores batches of commands.. anyway, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After our discussion in chat, we found that if `chrome` is not installed, it will not launch. therefore simply use:

```
start "" "chrome" --kiosk --fullscreen --incognito "https://www.netflix.com/"
```

We need to ensure that all other chrome windows are closed as it will not open kiosk mode if chrome is already open.

That means if `chrome` is not found by default using `start` it is not installed.

Older tries:

This `batch` file is assuming chrome is installed correctly:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('where chrome') do (
start "" "%%a" --kiosk --fullscreen --incognito "website url"
)
pause
```

Once you confirmed that it is working, simply remove `echo` from the last line to actually perform the start.

The next option, seeing as `where` might not work is too search for the file.

```
pushd C:
cd\
for /F "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d /s chrome.exe') do (
  start "" "%%a" --kiosk --fullscreen --incognito "https://www.netflix.com/in/"
)
pause
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply, hope u understand my question...i want to use that installed location in a variable and use that variable for my code instead of full manually typed path

Comment: @learner copy the code in my answer, exactly, and paste into a file and name it `myfile.cmd` DO NOT change anything in the batchfile, save it and run it, then let me know what happens.

Comment: @learner Try now please.. you needed to remove echo, please read answers carefully. Anyway, copy the code again and try

Comment: in cmd window iam getting "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)."

Comment: then there are issues with your installations.

Comment: already i am running my bat file and its working fine in my system..if there is any installation issue my bat also will not work ..right?

Comment: No, what I am saying is that the installation does not place the paths in the environment, it works yes, but `where` will not find it. I will update my solution now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169405/discussion-between-learner-and-gerhard-barnard).

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is:

```
start "" chrome.exe --kiosk --fullscreen --incognito "website url"
```

It is necessary to specify an empty title with `""` or command **START** interprets the first double quoted string as optional title string. Run in a command prompt window `start /?` for help on this command and its options.

The reason for starting successfully *Chrome* without full path and without its folder path being included in environment variable `PATH` is explained in answer on [Where is START searching for executables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386403/3074564)

`chrome.exe` is (usually) registered correct according to guidelines of Microsoft for [Application Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration). So **START** is capable finding the path of *Chrome* application itself.

Solution with first checking if *Chrome* is installed and registered at all:

```
@echo off
%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\chrome.exe" >nul 2>&1
if not errorlevel 1 start "" chrome.exe --kiosk --fullscreen --incognito "website url"
```