# How to Randomize the browsers from opening a webpage

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have this PowerShell command line which usually opens a webpage via Google Chrome, but I would like that to open randomly with Chrome and Firefox.

```
start-process -FilePath chrome.exe "www.quora.com"
```

Comment: `start-process -FilePath ('chrome.exe','firefox.exe'|get-random) "www.quora.com"`. probably this works, if not use the full path of both browsers.

Comment: @santiago-squarzo Is there a way to randomize the browsers for Batch-file as well?

Comment: You can use `%RANDOM%` in a batch file to do random things.  You should try to write a solution, and if you run into problems, ask a new question showing what you've done and asking for helping resolving the problems.

Comment: @anon-coward Hey, I tried and those are the results I found which ends with error. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

One PowerShell solution for usage in a PowerShell script or in PowerShell console window is as posted by [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon):

```
start-process -FilePath ('chrome.exe','firefox.exe'|get-random) "https://www.quora.com"
```

For understanding the two used PowerShell cmdlets and how they work, open a PowerShell console window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely the two help pages displayed for the two cmdlets very carefully.

- `help start-process`
- `help get-random`

One batch file solution is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set /A "Browser=%RANDOM% & 1"
if %Browser% == 0 (set "Browser=chrome") else set "Browser=firefox"
start "" %Browser%.exe "https://www.quora.com"
endlocal
```

The first two command lines just define the required execution environment completely and creates a new environment variables list as copy of the current environment variables list and the last line just results in restoring the initial execution environment and environment variables list. The second and the last command line could be omitted if it is no problem to depend on Windows defaults or what the process calling this batch file defines as execution environment.

The third line uses an arithmetic expression to apply on a random number a **bitwise AND** with `1` to get assigned to the environment variable `Browser` randomly either `0` or `1`.

The third line could be also:

```
set /A Browser=%RANDOM% %% 2
```

This arithmetic expression divides a random number by two and gets the remainder `0` or `1` assigned to the environment variable `Browser`.

The fourth line uses an **IF** condition to redefine the environment variable `Browser` on having currently the value `0` with the string `chrome` and otherwise with the string `firefox`.

The fifth line uses command `start` to start either `chrome.exe` or `firefox.exe` as separate process on which `cmd.exe` does not wait for self-termination before continuation of processing of the batch file with passing the URL to started executable. `""` defines an empty string as optional title for the console window not opened at all as the two browsers are Windows applications with a graphic user interface.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `help echo` or `echo /?`
- `help endlocal` or `endlocal /?`
- `help if` or `if /?`
- `help set` or `set /?`
- `help setlocal` or `setlocal /?`
- `help start` or `start /?`

See also:

- [An A-Z Index of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [An A-Z Index of Windows PowerShell commands](https://ss64.com/ps/)
- [Windows CMD Shell How-to guides and examples](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- [Windows PowerShell How-to guides and examples](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax.html)
- [Where is "START" searching for executables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382626/where-is-start-searching-for-executables)
  `powershell.exe` does the same. **PowerShell** and **CMD** use the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) to start the *Chrome* or *Firefox* process.